# !!vue?inject! not working; not returning factory function as expected

Tags: webpack, jasmine, karma-jasmine, vue.js

Error

```
TypeError: Object is not a constructor (evaluating 'DataTableInjector'
```

Package.js

```
"vue-loader": "^8.3.0",
"inject-loader": "^2.0.1",
"webpack": "^1.12.2",
```

Code:

```
const DataTableInjector = require('!!vue?inject!./../../../js/components/DataTable.vue');

let DataTable = DataTableInjector({
  'lodash/debounce': 'injected dep'
});
```

The inject loader should be taking the vue template DataTable and returning a factory function which I can pass a dependency override object to, yet it's returning a plain object just as the error suggests.

I thought this error was the result of a versioning issue, although I'm using the correct versions of webpack, inject-loader, and vue-loader. So that can't be it.

I know that both loaders are in fact available globally by just doing a require call for both loaders and returning a function for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to update the karma configuration file to use webpack instead of browserify.

I used the config file that can be found [here](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/testing.html).

**A quick explanation:**

All the test files were being packaged up with browserify before being executed. Browserify, to my knowledge, simply includes the contents of a file and all it's dependencies (by following all the `require`s) into a single file. With that said, Webpack does this in it's own way, AND with it's own bells and whistles.

When webpack bundles the file, it understands what `!!vue?injext!` means in the require call and processes the dependency properly. Browerify didn't know what this meant.

So now webpack can actually take the component file, pass it through it's loaders, and return the factory function as expected.